# TimerTask and Handler, effect on battery consumption

Tags: android

In  my application I  update a text box with the latitude/longitude values of the centre of the displayed Mapview. I'm doing this by means of a TimerTask which sends a message to to a handler every second.

Is this an inefficient way of doing this, in terms of CPU load/battery consumption?

If so is there a more efficient way of updating the text whenever the centre of the view changes?

This is not connected with GPS, as in one mode of my app I can turn the GPS off and scroll and pan around the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this an inefficient way of doing this, in terms of CPU load/battery consumption?

I'd use `postDelayed()` to schedule a `Runnable` (which reschedules itself via `postDelayed()` to create your timing loop), so you can avoid the implicit background thread involved in `TimerTask`. Otherwise, this isn't particularly inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. At first glance it appears that my drawing of a MapOverlay (extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay) is what puts the drain on the battery. Its 'draw' method runs every few millisec outside my control. I skip doing any intensive calculations if the position hasn't changed since last time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NickT: Off the top of my head, no. With the Google Maps stuff being closed-source, it is difficult to determine what causes overlays to be re-drawn. If you have not done so already, collect method traces of your app and examine them in Traceview -- that may give you some clues.

Comment: Thanks, Traceview - I've been trying to remember the name of that tool and it just wouldn't come. Now I know!

Comment: Why not use a Timer to schedule the TimerTask?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: `Timer` and `TimerTask` use a background thread. If you are in an activity, wanting to do updates periodically, a background thread for timing is not very useful, since you cannot update the UI on that thread anyway. `postDelayed()` can give you the same sort of timing loop, without the extra thread overhead.

Comment: "you cannot update the UI on that thread" - Says who?  I have built a music app, and I'm updating the progressbar on the player every second like that (in my Activity).

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: `ProgressBar` is one of the few widgets where Google went ahead and made it thread-safe for calls to `setProgress()` and kin. The vast majority of widgets cannot be updated from a background thread.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Perhaps they added similar support to `setText()` on `TextView`. You are welcome to [read the documentation where they say not to modify the UI from a background thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads). This is also covered in [the training portion of the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) And you are welcome to look at [all the questions discussing `CalledFromWrongThreadException`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+CalledFromWrongThreadException).

Comment: Ok, let me clarify what I'm doing.  Essentially, I am calling a method in my Activity from the TimerTask.  That method updates the UI.  So, in that scenario, it is not considered "from a background thread"...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Calling a method on an activity does not magically change the thread your code is running on. If you have additional concerns about this, please open a fresh StackOverflow question, as we have gone beyond a mere clarification of an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Timer task with Handler example is [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html)